Problem identifying a specific email sender
I am facing a problem at work where I need to create the following script/automation using Python:

Read the subject and content of an email in Outlook to check if a request has been confirmed. Based on this information, act as follows:
If the request has not been confirmed, reply to the email requesting a response.
If the request has been confirmed, send an email confirming that the operation was successfully completed.

However, I'm stuck on a problem trying to identify the email sender. I'm encountering the following error: "/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=D5C4A87552E64C4F879F178A9710A189- sender's name"
The script itself returns normal "@outlook.com" e-mails, but not with specific domains on it....
I've tried many alternatives to solve this problem, but it seems impossible... I'm a begginer at coding, so sorry for the incovenience (Btw, I'm running this code in Jupyter / Anaconda3)
Here is my code showing my progress so far:
import win32com.client
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Connect to Outlook
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')

# Access the Inbox
inbox = namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)

# Function to search for emails containing any term from the list in the body or subject
def mail_body_search(terms, folder):
    term_counts = {term: 0 for term in terms}  # Dictionary to store counts of each term
    relevant_messages = []  # List to store relevant emails
    senders = set()  # Set to store unique sender emails

    # Filter emails that contain any term in the body or subject
    for message in folder.Items:  # Iterate over items in the folder
        for term in terms:  # Check each term in the list
            if term.lower() in message.Body.lower() or term.lower() in message.Subject.lower():
                relevant_messages.append((message, message.Parent.Name))  # Add relevant email
                term_counts[term] += 1  # Increment count for the found term
                senders.add(message.SenderEmailAddress)  # Add sender's email to the set
                break  # If the term is found, no need to check other terms for this email

    return relevant_messages, term_counts, senders  # Return the list of found emails, term counts, and unique senders

# List of terms to search
search_terms = ['Teste', 'Testing with python']

# Call the function to search for emails with any of the terms in the Inbox
results, term_counts, senders = mail_body_search(search_terms, inbox)

# Display the total number of emails found
print(f'A total of {len(results)} emails were found.')

# Display the number of emails found for each term
for term, count in term_counts.items():
    print(f'{count} emails were found for "{term}".')

# Display the unique sender emails
print('Unique sender emails:')
for sender in senders:
    print(sender)


That /O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=D5C4A87552E64C4F879F178A9710A189- sender's name isn't an error.  Please include the actual error.

That is not an error - it is a perfectly fine looking EX-type address (as opposed to SMTP). Check MailItem.SenderEmailType property. If it is "EX", use MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress (be prepared to handle nulls), otherwise use MailItem.SenderEmailAddress like you do now.
On a general note, never loop through all items in a folder - you would never use a SELECT in SQL without a WHERE clause, right? Use Items.Restrict or Items.Find/FindNext.
On a more nitpicking note, consider all Outlook properties expensive - cache the values of (Body, Subject, SenderEmailAddress, etc.) before entering your for term in terms: loop, especially since you call lower() on each step, whcih is not al all necessary. And both loops would not be necessary if you create the right search criteria with all search terms to be used in Items.Restrict / Items.Find.
